# how can i modify spring.redis.host config and neednot restart springboot project?

Tags: java, spring, redis, restart, spring-data-redis

My old config like

```
spring.redis.host=192.168.1.1
```

Now I want to modify

```
spring.redis.host=192.168.1.2
```

But need not restart My project, How can I do that?

Comment: Please specify your real problem. Do you really need to implement live reload for configuration files or you need to reconnect to modified Redis host if it's changed? It's two different problem and two different possible solution.,

Answer (score 1):

ok, I found the answer:

```
        RedisTemplate template = (RedisTemplate) applicationContext.getBean("redisTemplate");
        JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory = (JedisConnectionFactory) template.getConnectionFactory();
        //关闭连接池
        redisConnectionFactory.destroy();
        redisConnectionFactory.setShardInfo(null);
        redisConnectionFactory.setHostName(host);
        redisConnectionFactory.setPort(port);
        redisConnectionFactory.setPassword(password);
        redisConnectionFactory.setDatabase(database);
        //重新创建连接池
        redisConnectionFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
        template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
```